# How do I conditionally replace a column from one file with one from another?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

File1 begins with:

```
 1 1
 1 3
 2 4
 1 5
 1 6
 1 7
 1 10
 1 13
 1 15
 1 17
```

File2 begins with:

```
0 MET 1
0 GLN 2
0 VAL 3
0 ILE 4
0 LEU 5
0 LEU 6
0 ASP 7
0 LYS 8
0 VAL 9
0 ALA 10
```

I want to replace column 1 in File2, with column 1 in File1, ONLY if column 2 in File1 exists in as column 3 in File2.

So my expected result would be:

```
1 MET 1
0 GLN 2
1 VAL 3
2 ILE 4
1 LEU 5
1 LEU 6
1 ASP 7
0 LYS 8
0 VAL 9
1 ALA 10
```

I've been trying awk with or without sed and I haven't gotten it work.  I know there is an easy answer to this.  Using loops hasn't worked for me either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, sorry for not putting my attempts in

Comment: @NicholasKovacs The phrase "ONLY if column 2 in File1 exists in as column 3 in File2" doesn't make sense to me, could you please give a better explanation of your requirement?  Further, in your exemplar output I see a single "2" in the first column of line 4, but in File1 I see a "1" in the corresponding position.

Comment: Looking at the answer by Akshay I see what you meant, sorry for bothering.

Comment: Thanks for looking!  My post was not clear, I will be sure to clarify in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Try***

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$2]=$1;next}{$1 = ( $3 in A ) ? A[$3] : 0}1' file1 file2
```

**Tested Like this**

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat f1
 1 1
 1 3
 2 4
 1 5
 1 6
 1 7
 1 10
 1 13
 1 15
 1 17


akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat f2
0 MET 1
0 GLN 2
0 VAL 3
0 ILE 4
0 LEU 5
0 LEU 6
0 ASP 7
0 LYS 8
0 VAL 9
0 ALA 10


akshay@Aix:/tmp$ awk 'FNR==NR{A[$2]=$1;next}{$1 = ( $3 in A ) ? A[$3] : 0}1' f1 f2
1 MET 1
0 GLN 2
1 VAL 3
2 ILE 4
1 LEU 5
1 LEU 6
1 ASP 7
0 LYS 8
0 VAL 9
1 ALA 10
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!  There are a couple constructs in there that I did not know how to use, but now I understand what they do.